IV Estimation, Direct and Indirect Effects
Suppose that I have a setup as follows, where $y_i$ is an outcome of interest, and $x_i$ is some endogenous regressor. The aim is to estimate $\beta$. Now suppose there is a variable $z_i$ that is correlated with $x_i$ and is uncorrelated with the error $\varepsilon_i$. Below, it is common to suppose that IV esitmation only works if $\gamma=0$. That is, there is no direct effect of the instrument on the outcome.
$$ y_i = a + \beta x_i + \gamma z_i+ \varepsilon_i $$
$$ x_i = b + \delta z_i + u_i $$
$$ E[z_i, \varepsilon] = 0 $$
$$ E[z_i, x_i] \neq 0 $$
$$ E[x_i, \varepsilon_i] \neq 0 $$
My question is, what is wrong with running the IV estimation anyway and included the instrument as a covariate in the second-stage regression? It does not seem as though the coefficient estimates would be biased. Would the problem be one of interpretation? Lastly, could this be useful in understanding the indirect effect of the instrument on the outcome?

Let $Y$ and $X$ represent the outcome and exposure variables, respectively, with the true data-generating process described by:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y &= \alpha + \beta X + \gamma Z + \epsilon, \\
X &= \theta + \delta Z + \upsilon,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\epsilon$ and $\upsilon$ are error terms. Here, $X$ is endogenous for $Y$, meaning  $\operatorname{Cov}(X, \epsilon) \neq 0$.
Exogeneity and Bias from an Invalid Instrument
If the variable $Z$ directly influences $Y$ (i.e., $\gamma \neq 0$), then $Z$ is an invalid instrument due to the violation of the exogeneity assumption. Using $Z$ as an instrument in such a case would yield inconsistent estimates for $\beta$.
If one were to proceed using $Z$ as an instrumental variable, the target estimand would be given by:
$$
\beta_{IV} = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(Z, Y)}{\operatorname{Cov}(Z, X)}.
$$
Substituting the true model for $Y$ into this expression:
$$
\beta_{IV} = \frac{\beta \operatorname{Cov}(Z, X) + \gamma \operatorname{Var}(Z) + \operatorname{Cov}(Z, \epsilon)}{\operatorname{Cov}(Z, X)}.
$$
If $Z$ is uncorrelated with $\epsilon$, i.e., $ \operatorname{Cov}(Z, \epsilon) = 0$, this simplifies to:
$$
\beta_{IV} = \beta + \frac{\gamma \operatorname{Var}(Z)}{\operatorname{Cov}(Z, X)}.
$$
Assuming $Z$ is relevant, i.e., $\delta \neq 0$, the covariance $\operatorname{Cov}(Z, X)$ is then given by:
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(Z, X) =\operatorname{Cov}(Z,\theta+\delta Z+\upsilon)= \delta \operatorname{Var}(Z)+\operatorname{Cov}(Z,\upsilon).
$$
Substituting this back, the IV estimand becomes:
$$
\beta_{IV} = \beta + \frac{\gamma}{\delta+\operatorname{Cov}(Z,\upsilon)/\operatorname{Var}(Z)}.
$$
This result shows that $\beta_{IV}$ equals the true causal effect $\beta$ only when $\gamma = 0$. Otherwise,
$\beta_{IV}$ is biased, with the bias given by:
$$
\text{Bias}(\beta_{IV}) = \frac{\gamma}{\delta+\operatorname{Cov}(Z,\upsilon)/\operatorname{Var}(Z)},
$$
which it is still non-zero when $\gamma,\delta\neq 0$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(Z,\upsilon)=0$, and it gets worse the "larger" $\gamma$ is.
This bias exists at the population level and does not vanish with increasing sample size, making any resulting estimator inconsistent.

As quick follow-up, this implies that although $\delta$ can be estimated consistently, due to the inconsistent estimate for $\beta$, we cannot get a good estimate of $\gamma$ and hence $\beta$ ultimately cannot be recovered?

@DarkenEconomics Well, the IV procedure won't give you an automatic consistent estimator for $\beta$. But let's say your data is generated by the described models, and $\operatorname{Cov}(Z,\upsilon)=0$, so $Z$ is exogenous for $X$. Then you could estimate $\beta_{IV}$ by using invalid IV $Z$,  estimate its bias by plugging in consistent/good estimator for $\gamma,\delta$, and then remove such bias from the "IV" estimate in a post-hoc procedure.

Right but that's what I was asking: it seems to me that the post-hoc procedure may not work because we may not be able to estimate $\gamma$ consistently if our estimate for $\beta$ is biased.
